# How to solve eslint error on working styled-component css?

Tags: css, eslint, styled-components

I've the code below for the css of a styled-component div, but Es-lint keep displaying error on my ide sayin' "colon expected".

I've tried a lot of things to fix it but i still have no clue. Do i miss something obvious ?

Please note that this code is working fine, this is just an (anoying) IDE error.

[image: screenshot of the displayed error]

```
const NavButtonBgMixin = css`
  // ANIM
  ${({ location, galerieName, $firstload }) => {
    if (
      location === galerieName &&
      galerieName === "paintings" &&
      !$firstload
    ) {
      return mixinAnimLeftToRight;
    }
    if (
      location === galerieName &&
      galerieName === "illustrations" &&
      !$firstload
    ) {
      return mixinAnimRightToLeft;
    }
  }};

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: ${({ location, galerieName, theme }) =>
    location === galerieName
      ? theme.colors.accent
      : theme.colors.backgroundDimmed};
`;
```